# How to connect with BigQuery via Laravel google/cloud-bigquery?

Tags: php, laravel, google-bigquery

I Used google/cloud-bigquery to read and  insert into bigquery using laravel? but i got an error like `must be of type ?string, Google\Cloud\BigQuery\Table given`

```
    $bigQuery = new BigQueryClient(
        [
            'projectId' => $projectId,
            'keyFilePath' => $keyFilePath
        ]
    );

    $dataset = $bigQuery->dataset($datasetId);
    $table = $dataset->table($tableId);
    return $table;
```

[image: code]